# caffe make error undefined reference x86_64

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake, anaconda, caffe

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29585180/caffe-make-error-in-mac-os-10-9

Mac OS 10.9, Cuda 6.5, Opencv 2.4.11, Anaconda..

By removing -limgcodecs, I am getting the same error as before-

```
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX src/caffe/blob.cpp
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/benchmark.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/cudnn.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/im2col.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/insert_splits.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/io.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/math_functions.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp
NVCC src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/util/im2col.cu
NVCC src/caffe/util/math_functions.cu
CXX tools/caffe.cpp
CXX tools/compute_image_mean.cpp
CXX tools/convert_imageset.cpp
CXX tools/device_query.cpp
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
CXX tools/finetune_net.cpp
CXX tools/net_speed_benchmark.cpp
CXX tools/test_net.cpp
CXX tools/train_net.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp
CXX examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.cpp
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp
CXX examples/siamese/convert_mnist_siamese_data.cpp
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::imread(std::string const&, int)", referenced from:
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<float>::InternalThreadEntry() in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::WindowDataLayer<double>::InternalThreadEntry() in window_data_layer.o
      caffe::ReadImageToCVMat(std::string const&, int, int, bool) in io.o
  "cv::imencode(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)", referenced from:
      caffe::ReadImageToDatum(std::string const&, int, int, int, bool, std::string const&, caffe::Datum*) in io.o
  "leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)", referenced from:
      caffe::db::LevelDB::Open(std::string const&, caffe::db::Mode) in db.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

.............................................................................

Also I tried  to install opencv 3.0,

$ brew install -devel opencv

but is giving the foll CMake error-

```
==> Installing opencv from homebrew/homebrew-science
==> Using Homebrew-provided fortran compiler.
This may be changed by setting the FC environment variable.
==> Downloading https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.0.0-beta.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv-3.0.0-beta.tar.gz
==> Downloading https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tdsmith/f67fd567702f2b51dacd/
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/opencv--patch-be689ac2ce44edfb1f8f9bdaf11e3cd5933fe26e9195ff57e391e6c49b3a1607.diff
==> Patching
patching file modules/python/common.cmake
Hunk #1 succeeded at 62 (offset 12 lines).
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.0.0-beta -DCMAKE_
DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
-DWITH_CUDA=ON

CMake Error: The source directory "/tmp/opencv20150412-21783-107bcd/opencv-3.0.0-beta/macbuild/DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

Any help appreciated.

---

Finally I installed opencv3 using cmake and not through brew. But now there seems to the same error- undefined symbols but with leveldb-

```
PROTOC src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto
CXX src/caffe/blob.cpp
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
CXX src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layer_factory.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.cpp
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
CXX src/caffe/solver.cpp
CXX src/caffe/syncedmem.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/benchmark.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/cudnn.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/db.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/im2col.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/insert_splits.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/io.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/math_functions.cpp
CXX src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.cpp
NVCC src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/power_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/split_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.cu
NVCC src/caffe/util/im2col.cu
NVCC src/caffe/util/math_functions.cu
CXX tools/caffe.cpp
CXX tools/compute_image_mean.cpp
CXX tools/convert_imageset.cpp
CXX tools/device_query.cpp
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
CXX tools/finetune_net.cpp
CXX tools/net_speed_benchmark.cpp
CXX tools/test_net.cpp
CXX tools/train_net.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp
CXX examples/cifar10/convert_cifar_data.cpp
CXX examples/mnist/convert_mnist_data.cpp
CXX examples/siamese/convert_mnist_siamese_data.cpp
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "leveldb::DB::Open(leveldb::Options const&, std::string const&, leveldb::DB**)", referenced from:
      caffe::db::LevelDB::Open(std::string const&, caffe::db::Mode) in db.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

I even tried to re-install leveldb but the problem persists. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I had to revert back to opencv 2.4.11. Uninstalled brew and all its dependencies. Loaded Cuda 7.0. Also added the ENV flags in dependencies with -stdlib=libc++ option. This solved the problem for me, although I still don't know the cause.